# ¿Por qué el nombre Yenifer no lleva acento?

Tags: acentuación, nombres-propios

La pronunciación de este nombre es Y**e**nifer y no Yen**i**fer o Yenif**e**r. Es entonces una palabra esdrújula. Sin embargo, en ningún lado lo veo con acento, incluso en prensa formal (e.g. Yenifer [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias-america-latina-62513311)).

Este nombre es claramente la españolización de un nombre inglés ([Jennifer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_(given_name))). ¿Eso lo exime de las reglas de acentuación? Entiendo el caso que que el nombre sea la versión en inglés, como por ejemplo Jennifer López, cuyo primer nombre no lleva acento, pero el apellido sí.

Answer (score 4):

La acentuación está normalizada en el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas de la Real Academia Española. Lo que tiene que ver con tu pregunta está en [el ítem 6 de la entrada de 'Tilde'](https://www.rae.es/dpd/tilde) de este diccionario.

En resumen, una palabra extranjera -como *Jennifer*- respeta la ortografía original y, por lo tanto en este caso no lleva tilde. Pero una palabra españolizada, como *Yénifer*, debería adaptarse a la ortografía española. De hecho, casi la totalidad de los nombres que podríamos decir sin problemas que son "españoles", son adaptaciones de otros idiomas, como *Óscar* (irlandés) o *Raúl* (inglés). Si Óscar y Raúl tienen tilde, entonces ***Yénifer* sí tiene tilde**.

Otra cosa es que tú decidas escribirla sin tilde, porque es tu nombre y porque finalmente tú haces con tu nombre lo que quieres. Si deseas, le pones un acento circunflejo sobre la 'f', allá tú. Razones hay: *"Me llamo 'Erica' sin tilde porque en el registro de nacimiento se equivocaron y lo escribieron así"*. *"Soy 'Ursula' sin tilde porque así está en mi carné nacional, y eso es lo legal"*. *"Me llamo 'Victor', pero sin tilde, porque mis padres eran suecos..."*. Como sea, puedes excusarte cuanto quieras, pero escribir 'Yenifer' sin tilde es incorrecto *en español*.